# MouseBinding gesture strings in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Mouse gestures can be bound to commands using the `MouseBinding InputBinding`,

**for example:**

```
<Grid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Gesture="LeftClick"/>
</Grid.InputBindings>
```

In that example, the `LeftClick` gesture is used. What is the full list of gesture strings? I'm looking for a left mouse button down gesture, if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

That is a [MouseAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction(v=vs.110).aspx) value. You can see possible values in the documentation. Mouse down is not a built-in gesture. Only various clicks and double clicks are in the enumeration.

It is possible to make your own input bindings by creating classes that extend `InputBinding` and `InputGesture`. You can reference the [implementation of MouseBinding](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/MouseBinding.cs) for an example. Alternatively, you can find a different way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a left mouse button down gesture, if it exists.

That would be the `LeftClick` mouse action that you are currently using.

If you want to invoke a *command* when the `MouseLeftButtonDown` *event* occurs, you could do this using an interaction trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this.

**Handling events in an MVVM WPF application:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

The `EventTrigger` class is included in th Expression Blend SDK which you can download from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801.